# Recommended data structure/format for web MVC applications?

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications

What's a good data structure for use in MVC web applications to use to pass data into view to ensure standardization and keep the view as non-coder friendly as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom model class and keep it as non-coder friendly as possible :)
How you construct the model class strongly depends on the specific page.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it really simple you could just pass a dictionary with string keys and value.

Answer (score 0):

I like django structure. It's very flexible.
Example:

```
project/
       apps/
            app1/
                 models.py
                 views.py
                 forms.py
                 templates/ #or into root templates path
                 url.py #to dispatch
                 etc..
       templates/
                app1/
                    templates
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have created class for each of M,V,C... it would be good to use a class for data structure with member fields that contain data to be shown in the view. it is better to have separate data structure classes for each entity. But in your case i.e. in case of view, if your view consists of different sections, then use separate data structure classes.
When you instantiate your view, create an object of the data structure as well. then use getters to fetch the data and pass it to either the getter of view's object or the constructor itself.